# VSCode: Set environment variables via script

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code

I have a shell script `env.sh` containing statements like `export ENV_VAR1 = 1`. On Linux terminal, I can use `. env.sh` or `source env.sh` to set the environment variables.

How to set the environment variables in  Visual Studio Code (VSCode) via `env.sh`?

I have tried multiple approaches:

1) I start (VSCode - `/usr/share/code/code`) after sourcing the script as follows

`. env.sh
/usr/share/code/code`

2) I used the extension "Auto Run Command" to call `. env.sh` at workspace loading time.

But these do not work. For example, while using the Jupyter extension, I get errors in `import matplotlib` even though the import works when I use the Python interpreter inside the Linux terminal above.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using an [environment variable definition file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file).

Answer (score 1):

For bash, you can can create a shell/source script and source it as an argument to the terminal the `settings.json` in the workspace root.

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": [
        "--rcfile",
        "bin/init_dev_env.sh"
    ]
}
```

Refs:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_shell-arguments
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm trying to use your suggestion but it's not working, I've tried to edit both setting files: `root/.vscode/settings.json` and the main `settings.json` via user setting, What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a profile for the integrated terminal for a specific workspace. For example for zsh:

.vscode/settings.json:

```json
{
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "Init dev env": {
      "path": "zsh",
      "args": ["-c", "source ${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/init.sh"],
    },
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "Init dev env"
}
```

.vscode/init.sh:

```bash
echo "Setup dev env"
export TEST=1
exec zsh -i # This makes sure the terminal is interactive and won't be closed.
```

This way you can start a new terminal with this profile that will automatically run the initialization script.